# dompdf codeigniter , i am trying to render two htmls i get error on render

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

dompdf codeigniter , i am trying to render two htmls i get error on render

here the error that happens when i run the second render

```
[Wed Jul 03 09:18:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found.  Not good.' in /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/inline_positioner.cls.php:38\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(546): Inline_Positioner->position()\n#1 /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/inline_frame_reflower.cls.php(37): Frame_Decorator->position()\n#2 /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(556): Inline_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL)\n#3 /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/page_frame_reflower.cls.php(138): Frame_Decorator->reflow()\n#4 /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(556): Page_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL)\n#5 /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/dompdf.cls.php(817): Frame_Decorator->reflow()\n#6 /var/www/onplans/application/controllers/timeline.php(957): DOMPDF->render()\n#7 [internal function]: Timeline->generate_report_ in /var/www/onplans/application/libraries/dompdf/include/inline_positioner.cls.php on line 38, referer:


if ( $reportCouvs[0] == 1 ) { 
    //  $this->pdf->load_html( 'reports/report_comb_1', $Ddata );
    $this->pdf->load_view( 'reports/report_comb_1', $Ddata );
    $this->pdf->render();
    $pdfoutput = $this->pdf->output();
    $filename = "$report_dir/"."cover3.pdf";
    $fp = fopen( $filename, "a" );
    fwrite( $fp, $pdfoutput );
    fclose( $fp );
    $this->pdf->load_view( 'reports/report_comb_2', $Ddata );
    $this->pdf->render();
    $pdfoutputu = $this->pdf->output();
    $filenameu = "$report_dir/"."imagleft3.pdf";
    $fp = fopen( $filenameu, "a" );
    fwrite( $fp, $pdfoutputu);
    fclose( $fp );

} else if( $reportCouvs[0] == 2 ) {
    $this->pdf->load_view('reports/report_comb_2', $Ddata ); 
}
```

on the second render the app crashes

is it possible to render two files with dompdf

Comment: Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found.  Not good.'

Comment: this happens when a run the second render

Comment: What is the HTML you try to render? Somebody says that multibyte extension of PHP must be enabled. Is it enabled on the host?

Comment: I think you can output only one thing by the browser at a time.

Comment: mbstring
Multibyte Support  enabled
Multibyte string engine  libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation  disabled

Comment: mbstring Multibyte Support looks enabled

Comment: That error basically indicates that there was no HTML content to parse. Somewhere along the line your code got munged to the point that when you imported into dompdf it was lost completely.

Comment: It is possible to render multiple PDFs though you can't reuse the same dompdf instance. You have to destroy and create a new instance, or use two different variable assignments. You don't indicate (i.e. through a link) which plugin you're using so we can't evaluate your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up against this issue also. 
This error can happen for a few reasons. There are three options you can check:

- reinstalling your DOMPDF library
- make sure mbstring is installed/configured/enabled for PHP
- make sure you are re-initialising, or creating a new instance of DOMPDF when looping.

As it sounds like you have already output one PDF successfully, this indicates the first two options are likely not the issue. We can't see your complete code that relates to the issue, but it seems probable it is the third option.

If it is the third, then you would make sure the loop that creates the pdfs started with the line:

```
$this->pdf = new DOMPDF();
```